# how to resolve java.lang.ExceptionInitializerError when using Mockito for JUnit

Tags: android, maven, junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm gonna crazy because of this error.

My code could be built, however, occurs `java.lang.ExceptionInitializerError.`

Here is my code

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@SE(api = "package... .isMethod()", type = TYPE.AUTO) 
@Before  
@Test 
public void testIsMethod_P01() throws Exception
{
    A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(true).when(a).isMethod();

    assertEquals(true, a.isMethod());
}
```

---

I'm using Eclipse and that shows the problem line is

```
A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
```

I guess the Exception was occured when creating Mocking object.

I tried many ways to resolve this problem...

```
System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getContext().getCacheDir().getPath()),
many annotations(Before, Test, RunWith etc...),
libs(about dex)
```

and even maven for dependencies

But, I'm not sure what's the problem exactly.
Please tell me reason and share the solution...

Comment: '@Before' and '@Test' both annotations on same method, this doesn't looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Drop your

```
@Before
```

annotation from above the method.